# How to use the shape tween with Actionscript 3.0?

Tags: flash, animation, actionscript, shapes, tween

I want to simply animate a shape using actionscript code. How would you create a shape tween in code, and use it to increase the width of the shape?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Flash Professional tweens in AS3, as it is a different process of creating graphics.

There are however tween engines (TweenLite/TweenMax are the most popular so far) that will let you tween almost any property: width, height, scale, x, y, alpha, even colours!

So to tween properties of a DisplayObject you can either download a tween engine (link will be provided at the bottom) or just write a simple EnterFrame/Timer event handler that will do what you want until you remove the event listener.

Link to TweenLite: http://www.greensock.com/tweenlite/